# How to read filenames saved as utf8 ( urdu / arabic characters ) in php?

Tags: php, sorting, utf-8, filenames, urdu

Please guide me :-
**1. How to read / save utf8 characters of filenames** saved in Urdu / Arabic language.    This worked from me  **$file_utf8 = iconv( "Windows-1256", "utf-8", $filepath );**  ,  but not reading all filenames, skipping over 80 %. 
I also need to

**2. sort the list of files** ( file names ) with respect to **time created and size**.

**3. Save the sorted list in a utf-8 txt file**  ,  solved this part with this code  :  Problem remains that **ALL filenames are not read**

```
$myDr = fopen("list.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");                              

foreach ($files as $f) 
    { 
    $path1 = iconv( "Windows-1256", "utf-8", $f ); 
    echo  $zz . " . " . $path1, "<br>\n"; 


        $txtpoet2 = "$path1 \r\n" ; 
        fwrite($myDr, $txtpoet2);                                           



    $zz++; 
    } 
fclose($myDr);
```

I have many images in directories and sub directories where I saved filename in Urdu language. "**ترے عشق کی انتہا چاہتا ہوں.png**"  .  I want to make a list of all directories and sub directories and **save in a unicode txt file**. I am unable to **read the Urdu characters in php** coding.

My environment is Windows 7 ( 64 bit) ,  Using XAMPP - apache as server.  I have tried C++ , but could not find the solution.

I am using following PHP to read all files in sub directories:-

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

function listdir($dir='.') 
    { 
    if (!is_dir($dir)) 
        { 
        return false; 
        } 

    $files = array(); 
    listdiraux($dir, $files); 

    return $files; 
    } 

function listdiraux($dir, &$files) 
    { 
    $handle = opendir($dir); 
    while ( false !==($file = readdir($handle)) ) 
        { 
        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') 
            { 
            continue; 
            } 
        $filepath = $dir == '.' ? $file : $dir . '/' . $file; 
        if (is_link($filepath))             continue; 
        if (is_file($filepath))             
            { 
            $files[] = $filepath;  

        else if (is_dir($filepath))         listdiraux($filepath, $files); 
        } 
    closedir($handle); 
    } 

$files = listdir('.'); 
sort($files, SORT_LOCALE_STRING); 
$zz = 0; 
foreach ($files as $f) 
    { 

    echo  $zz . " . " . $f, "<br>\n"; 
    $zz++; 

} 

?>
```

Source of this code is http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php  .

Thanking you all.

Comment: Dear Paul, it is some what a similar problem , yet not the same. I have searched web and all links  mentioned in the post.  Urdu is Language of Pakistan, it is in Arabic style, using almost Persian script. But different from Arabic, Persian and Hindi.   The solution is :      Add  this line  where file name ( $is read    :                          $file_utf8 = iconv( "Windows-1256", "utf-8", $filepath );      Thanks,

Comment: Dear Paul ( @PaulCrovella  ) One  problem :  while I was able to read Urdu utf-8 file names using above mentioned line of code,  the directory when read ,  is missing many files.   I have 60 files , having name in Urdu, and 70 files in English,  the function is reading/ displaying  only 6 /  maximum  8 in Urdu  and  all 70 files having names in English.      **Unable to read complete Directory contents. **

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution for Urdu**,  language spoken by over a billion humans, mostly India, Pakistan, Iran, Afghanistan.  In India,  its dialect is used but a different script / characters.
My appreciation for all members of  stackoverflow

You will find a lot of improvement in **www.rwpmall.com/urdu/poetry**

I needed this line in code

**

### $file_utf8 = iconv( "Windows-1256", "utf-8", $sub );

**

I am posting the complete solution for helping others:

```
<?php 
$dir = "."; 

function ReadFolderDirectory($dir) 
    { 
    $listDir = array(); 
    if($handler = opendir($dir)) { 
    while (($sub = readdir($handler)) !== FALSE) 
            { 
            if ($sub != "." && $sub != ".." && $sub != "Thumb.db") 
                { 
                if(is_file($dir."/".$sub)) 
                    { 
                    $file_utf8 = iconv( "Windows-1256", "utf-8", $sub );
                    $listDir[] = $sub; 
                    //  echo  $file_utf8 ."<br>";
                    echo  $dir."/".$file_utf8 ."<br>";
                    }
                elseif(is_dir($dir."/".$sub))
                    {
                    echo "  New Sub Directory :  >>>>     ". $dir."/".$sub . " <br> "; 
                    $listDir[$sub] = ReadFolderDirectory($dir."/".$sub); 
                    } 
                } 
            }    
            closedir($handler); 
        } 

        return $listDir;    
    } 
  ReadFolderDirectory($dir);   
?>
```

Regards.
May God grant us wisdom to make this Earth a better place for Humanity.

Comment: I found solution of twp parts ,   Reading UTF-8 Urdu charaters in filenames / directories and saving them as text file.  While I am able to get last file access fite, I am still stuck in accessing Time of Creation.  It will sort my all files in the sequence as I initially created them.

Comment: I am still stuck in accessing Time of Creation. My file names are a mix of normal English and UTF-8 ( Urdu 1056 ) Windows 1256 code page.

Comment: The problem is : I am using Windows 7 , NTFS  ( 64 Bit) and trying  PHP for UTF-8  ,  I suspect  ,  a gross error and a mismatch.    Somthing on UTF 16 to UTF-8  or  CodePage  ,  1056 / Windows 1256 may solve my problem.

Comment: Hi wasif, did you find a working solution ? I am having same problme in checking if file exists. if there is urdu / arabic in path it cannot read it and verify and give correct answer. thanks